# Which iOS audio API is designed for streaming large local audio files from disk with low latency?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, streaming, core-audio

I need to play very large audio files from disk, and streaming them into memory would be the most efficient.

Must I use OpenAL for this or is there another option?

Comment: How low latency do you require?  Are you manipulating the audio data at all, or do you just need to play a buffer?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [audio queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/musicaudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). They're simple to use, well-documented, and high-level. And I'd recommend using [extended audio file services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) to get the audio data out of the files.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, for uncompressed audio data, you can mmap huge files, and then just copy the samples from memory to the RemoteIO callback buffers.  The RemoteIO Audio Unit can be configured for even lower latency than Audio Queues.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use Audio Unit, it's the lowest level Audio API of Apple, so it's perfect for low latency..

You should first init Audio unit with remoteIO, them read buffer from your file in a while loop and push these buffers to AudioUnit in AudioUnit callback